# Inflating layout a child view to view of custom adapter is repeating in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I am developing an android app. In my app. I have to work with Listview using custom adapter. Even in the adapter I need to inflate child view to view of custom adapter. But I load the items to listview by segment by segment like pager. But when new segment of items is loaded, then child views are added again to existing row view.

This is the initial state of listview:

[image]

But child views are added like this when I bind new items to listview on scroll:

[image]

This is my custom adapter view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/user_timeline_main_layout"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/civ_timeline_profile"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/timeline_reason_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_timeline_username"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_timeline_reason"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_timeline_datetime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/timeline_action_content_container"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the timeline_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:text="This is item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

timeline_designer.xml is identical to timeline_item.xml.

This is my custom adapter:

```
public class UserTimelineAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TimelineItem> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<TimelineItem> values;

    static class ViewHolder{
        public CircleImageView civProfile;
        public TextView tvUsername;
        public TextView tvReason;
        public TextView tvDatetime;
        public LinearLayout actionContentContainer;
        public LinearLayout mainLayout;
    }

    public UserTimelineAdapter(Context contextParam,ArrayList<TimelineItem> valuesParam)
    {
        super(contextParam,-1,valuesParam);
        this.context = contextParam;
        this.values = valuesParam;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = convertView;
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if(rowView==null)
        {
            rowView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.user_timeline_row,null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.mainLayout = (LinearLayout)rowView.findViewById(R.id.user_timeline_main_layout);
            viewHolder.civProfile = (CircleImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.civ_timeline_profile);
            viewHolder.tvUsername = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_timeline_username);
            viewHolder.tvReason = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_timeline_reason);
            viewHolder.tvDatetime = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_timeline_datetime);
            viewHolder.actionContentContainer = (LinearLayout)rowView.findViewById(R.id.timeline_action_content_container);
            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else{
            viewHolder  = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }

        if(values.get(position).getProfileImagePath().isEmpty())
        {
            viewHolder.civProfile.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_designer_profile);
        }
        else{
            Picasso.with(context).load(values.get(position).getProfileImagePath()).into(viewHolder.civProfile);
        }

        viewHolder.tvUsername.setText(values.get(position).getUsername());
        viewHolder.tvReason.setText(values.get(position).getReason());
        viewHolder.tvDatetime.setText(values.get(position).getDatetime());

        if(values.get(position).getItemId()>0)
        {
            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.timeline_item,viewHolder.mainLayout,false);
            viewHolder.actionContentContainer.addView(view);
        }
        else{
            //designer
            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.timeline_designer,viewHolder.mainLayout,false);
            viewHolder.actionContentContainer.addView(view);
        }

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

Why is that happening? How can I fix my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you re-use the main view by using the pattern that uses a view tag, but on the re-used view you still inflate and add another view every time:

```
if(values.get(position).getItemId()>0)
{
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.timeline_item,viewHolder.mainLayout,false);
    viewHolder.actionContentContainer.addView(view);
}
```

So, instead of inflating this item on the re-used view (i.e. when `rowView != null`), try finding this view by sth like `rowView.findViewById(R.id.timeline_item_id);` if you need to update its text, for example, or anyhow change it.

If you don't need to change it, just don't look it up and **don't** inflate and add.

Comment: I m gonna green up the answer soon.